# Twitter Bootstrap Sticky Footer on iPhone?

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap

Do I need to do anything special to my mobile app to get the [Twitter Sticky Footer](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html) working on iPhone?

**HTML:**

Birthday Reminders

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Please use the tabs below to add a birthday reminder!</p>
      <div id="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div> <!-- /container -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  But I recommend using the bootstrap-responsive.css file in addition to the regular css file.

Comment: I have that too.  What is the correct footer structure>  I have updated my question

Comment: I think if you nest a container class div inside the div id footer, the bootstrap css delegates the proper code to stick the footer.  But the site is messed up big time right now, and I can't recall off the top of my head.  Sorry!